# Free Camera -orbit VirtualJoystick

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have problems with Virtual Joystick that responsible to control the camera “orbit” which rotate all Scene around the main player character, the problem the camera can see through the terrain/ground. How do I prevent that?

Please check the following screenshot and script  :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8gJU.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0NT9.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T5n9.jpg)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FreeCamera : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform lookAt;
    public VirtualJoystick camerajs;
    private float distance = 200.0f;
    private float currentx = 0.0f;
    private float currenty = 0.0f;
    private float sensitivityx = 1.0f;
    private float sensitivityy = 1.0f;
    private void Update()
    {
        currentx += camerajs.InputDirection.x * sensitivityx;
        currenty += camerajs.InputDirection.z * sensitivityy;
    }
    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 dir = new Vector3(0, 0, -distance);
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(currenty, currentx, 0);
        transform.position = lookAt.position + rotation * dir;
        transform.LookAt(lookAt);
    }
}
```

---

```
using UnityEngine; using System.Collections; using UnityEngine.UI; using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class VirtualJoystick : MonoBehaviour,IDragHandler,IPointerUpHandler,IPointerDownHandler {

    private Image bgImg;
    private Image joystickImg;
    public Vector3 InputDirection{ set; get;}
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        bgImg = GetComponent<Image> ();
        joystickImg = transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<Image> ();
        InputDirection = Vector3.zero;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    //void Update () {

    //}
    public virtual void OnDrag(PointerEventData ped)
    {
        Vector2 pos = Vector2.zero;
        if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle
            (bgImg.rectTransform,
                ped.position,
                ped.pressEventCamera,
                out pos)) {
            pos.x=(pos.x/bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x);
            pos.y=(pos.y/bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y);
            float x=(bgImg.rectTransform.pivot.x==1) ? pos.x*2+1 : pos.x*2-1;
            float y=(bgImg.rectTransform.pivot.y==1) ? pos.y*2+1 : pos.y*2-1;
            InputDirection=new Vector3(x,0,y);
            InputDirection=(InputDirection.magnitude>1) ? InputDirection.normalized : InputDirection;

            joystickImg.rectTransform.anchoredPosition=
                new Vector3(InputDirection.x*(bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x/3),InputDirection.z*(bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y/3));
            Debug.Log(InputDirection);
        }

    }
    public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData ped)
    {
        OnDrag (ped);

    }
    public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData ped)
    {


        //Here is the problem it just goes to zero so fast so my character also moves so fast...how can i make it so motth
        InputDirection =Vector3.zero;
        joystickImg.rectTransform.anchoredPosition =Vector3.zero;
    }
}
```

Comment: any help ......?

Comment: this issue is solved after adding unity box collider

Comment: this issue is solved after doing the following 
1- Add plan instead of terrain
2- Remove the plan default collider 
3- Add box collider to the plan
4- adding box collider to the target 
the issue related to camera raycast

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this issue is solved after adding unity box collider

this issue is solved after doing the following 1-   Add plan instead of terrain 2-  Remove the plan default collider 3- Add box collider to the plan 4- adding box collider to the target the issue related to camera raycast –